# Why does the activity indicator work on my Android emulator, but not my device?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin Forms project, and I am running into a weird issue with the Activity Indicator. On one view I have a list of selections, each of which opens a new view. While it is loading I want the activity indicator to display. Currently, this is working as expected on iOS and on the Android emulator. However, it won't work on an Android device. The view (a ContentPage) looks something like this:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="progressIndicator" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
        <ScrollView x:Name="scrollViewMain"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            ...
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Then in the code I am setting the `IsRunning` property to `true` when the item is selected, then I push the new page.

```
private void myList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressIndicator.IsRunning = true;

    if (e.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var selection = (PageSelection)e.SelectedItem;
        switch (selection.Id)
        {
            case 1:
                Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage1());
                break;
            case 2:
                Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage2());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Again, this code works exactly as expected on the emulator, but not at all on my Android device (Android 7.0) or my coworker's device (Android 9.0). Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

Edit: I have now tested this on a tablet, and it works fine there. So I guess it works fine on some devices.

Comment: I see an error in your code that may be related to your problem. You have a Grid with only one row and one column. Inside that grid you first put yout ActivityIndicator and then put your ScrollView on top of it. That's why I think you shouldn't be able to see ActivityIndicator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ArminRasoulian, I forgot to mention the ScrollView is set to hidden at the same time that the indicator is activated. That piece works on both the emulator and device. The only difference is on the device, when it's hidden, there's no indicator, just blank with the title bar until the data for the next screen loads.

Comment: @user2588873 Hi , it's a strange phenomenon . Could you share a link of sample project. I will check it.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I can still send a sample project in a bit, but I tested it on a tablet now and it works fine there. So I guess it does work on some devices, but not all.

Comment: @user2588873 Okey , maybe different devices have something differences can affect the result. It need more time to research to find the reason.